# What is the difference between CountVectorizer and CharNGramAnalyzer in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I have a confusion between CountVectorizer and  CharNGramAnalyzer. According to my understanding,

1. CountVectorizer builds a count matrix where rows are occurrences counts of different words taking into account the high-dimensional sparsity.
2. CharNGramAnalyzer builds a count matrix where rows are occurrences counts of different characters. Since it does not take into account words, its does not require to know separation between words and works well for languages other than English.

Am I correct about my understanding? If not, I would like a detailed explanation or any source explaining it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check your sklearn version. I feel that you are using an old version of sklearn. The explanation that you gave for `CountVectorizer` is not right. It does not count the number of different words in the corpus, at least not the current version.

As per the [docs of CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), you need to pass `analyzer='word'` to make the word count. In the latest version of sklearn, `CharNGramAnalyzer` is deprecated and now merged with `CountVectorizer`. Just do `analyzer='char'` to replicate `CharNGramAnalyzer`. To verify this check http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction.text has no entry for `CharNGramAnalyzer`